# Opencv or Numpy-- replace a list of pixels in an image, efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Hi OpenCV or Numpy Gurus,

I've been searching to an answer to this, but I'm surprised to not find it here or elsewhere...

I have a black image, and I want to replace a list of pixels (quite a large list) with a certain value.  In the future, the "certain value" will be a list of values, but for the moment, let's keep it simple.

Simplifying even further, I just use a 2-d array of single numbers below, instead of RGB values...
So, this fairly inefficient approach works for this sort of thing:

```
a = np.zeros((5, 5,1))

for i in np.asarray( ([2,3],[3,4]) ):
       a[i[0], i[1]] = 20
```

I was hoping there was a way to use `np.put` on a two dimensional array, where I don't rely on a python loop.

Now I had the suggestion that I could use

```
a[ ([2,3],[3,4]) = 20
```

However I notice when I use this approach in my real OpenCV problem it does not work.  This very inefficient approach does:

```
coords_list = ([3,5],[55,60],[25,90])
black_image =np.zeros((480,640,3))
for i in coords_list:
    black_image[i[1],i[0]] = [255,255,255]
```

I expect this is a simple question to many out there.

Thanks!

Comment: If you haave a list of coordinate pairs `coords` then the idiom would be `I, J = np.transpose(coords)` `a[I, J] = 20`

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can directly use your tuple of coordinates to index your matrix: a simple `a[([2, 3], [3, 4])] = 20` gives the exact same result as your for loop here.

Comment: Sorry, RomualdM, it does not seem to work with the situation I am working on...it produces a completely white image.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Paul Panzer and RomualdM...

This seems to do what I want, based on their comments...

```
coords_list = ([3,5],[55,60],[25,90])
black_image =np.zeros((480,640,3))
I,J = np.transpose(coords_list)
black_image[I,J] = [255,255,255]
cv2.imshow('black_image', black_image)
while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) #press esc to kill
    if (k == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```