# OpenCV copying a list of pixels from one image to another

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Hi OpenCV or Numpy Gurus,

Following on from my previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52867016/opencv-or-numpy-replace-a-list-of-pixels-in-an-image-efficiently)

I have a black image, and I want to replace a list of pixels (quite a large list) with a list of pixel values.

I can copy a single pixel colour into an image -- thanks to some users assistance:

```
coords_list = ([3,5],[55,60],[25,90])
black_image =np.zeros((480,640,3))
I,J = np.transpose(top_pot_coords)
black_image[I,J] =  [255,255,255]
```

However, I cannot just copy the pixel values in to the black_image (this does not work):

```
black_image[I,J] =  img[I,J]
```

I'm hoping this is a simple question to many out there.I've been working on this for a few hours, and I'm really not at the point where I can put together a solution, though I am learning.

Thanks for your help!

EDIT:

OK, this is embarassing -- not sure what I did before, but in the process of writing a minimal complete verifiable example, I've developed a minimal, complete, verifiable answer. Please see my own answer below.

Comment: OK, I'll see if I can make it a bit better...

Comment: Mad Lee -- how about you remove the downvote since I made the effort to produces a better example, and in the process I developed the answer below.

Comment: Sorry, my vote is locked by Stackoverflow unless you have edited your question.

Comment: OK Mad Lee, I've edited it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this is embarassing -- not sure what I did before, but in the process of writing a minimal complete verifiable example, I've developed a minimal, complete, verifiable answer. So, for those who might be interested...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
coords_list = np.array([[3,5],[40,25],[25,54]], dtype=np.uint8)
pixel_list =  np.array([[255,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,0,255]], dtype=np.uint8)
black_image =np.zeros((48,64,3))
cv2.imshow('black_image', black_image)
while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) #press esc to kill
    if (k == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I,J = np.transpose(coords_list)
black_image[I,J] =  [255,255,255]

cv2.imshow('black_image', black_image)
while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) #press esc to kill
    if (k == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()


black_image[I,J] =  pixel_list

cv2.imshow('black_image', black_image)
while (1):
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) #press esc to kill
    if (k == 27):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```